# How to do a wiki / wordpress style compare / diff in PHP?

Tags: php, diff

A bit like this from WordPress: [image: Wordpress diff]

Or this from MediaWiki: [image: Wikipedia diff]

I have tried several diff engines in PHP, the most comprehensive seem to be (http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php) and PEAR's Text_Diff, but I can't seem to find any option to have both versions stacked side by side like in the above images. I think that is easier to read than having both version in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have found a solution - by taking the WP_Text_Diff_Renderer_Table class from WordPress (wp-includes/wp-diff.php) which is used in conjuction with PEAR Text_Diff:

```
$diff = new Text_Diff('auto', array($lines1, $lines2));
$render = new WP_Text_Diff_Renderer_Table;
echo $render->render($diff);
```

When wrapped in  tags the above code produces the same HTML layout as the above WordPress screenshot. There are then four CSS rules to style:

- .diff-deletedline - the
  paragraph/line that is changed from
  the source text
- .diff-addedline - the paragraph/line
  that is changed in the destination
  text
- del - the individual word changed
  from the source
- ins - the individual word that is
  changed in the destination

More details here: http://www.webdevguides.co.uk/php-2/wordpress-style-diff-in-php

Comment: Now in 2018 I searched PEAR Text_Diff but saw "This package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded. Package has moved to channel pear.horde.org, package Horde_Text_Diff." See https://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Text_Diff/library or https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of finediff.php, which you refer to in your post.

Solution using PHP FineDiff class is quite simple: Get an HTML string of the diff using stock renderer FineDiff::renderDiffToHTMLFromOpcodes(), than you can use the same resulting string in two different DIVs, each CSS-styled appropriately, like so:

```
<?php
    ...
    $diff = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($fromText, $toText);
    $diffHTML = FineDiff::renderDiffToHTMLFromOpcodes($fromText, $diff);
    ?>
<div id="from"><?php echo $diffHTML; ?></div>
<div id="to"><?php echo $diffHTML; ?></div>
```

Then it is a matter of styling properly to show only what you wish:

```
#from ins {display:none}
#to del {display:none}
```

Edit: ON second thought, I realize that you might want both sides to be anchored appropriately together, which my solution won't do.